# QUERY IMPORTRANGE function is adding additional information into the header name

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I've got a query importrange function which for some reason is adding in the first 4 rows of data below the header into the header name:

Example

Row header from source data: Site
Row header result queryimportrange: Site JMCC JMCC JMCC JMCC

Row header from source data: Package
Row header result from queryimportrange: Package P8 P5 P5 P5

I can see that it's clearly pulling through the first 4 rows from the source file but for some reason it's only this file that's doing it as I have copies of this for other sources of data using the same query

Could it be too many queryimportrange functions into one another or something else?

I would like to share the file but it has sensitive information so I can't but I have included the original query below with some alterations to the names

`=query(importrange("15a22123F£frc8P6e2NFrzdA$gHD5-PizrpaDSpLX","2. Cost Details!E1:S"),"Select Col1, Col4,Col8,Col9,Col10,sum(Col7) WHERE Col1 is not null GROUP BY Col8, Col1,Col4,Col9,Col10  PIVOT Col15 LABEL sum(Col7) 'PO Value Remaining (£)'")`

Just want the headers to pull through - not the first 4 rows of data

Comment: just in case; use [this](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/80895004?hl=en) & [this](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/154225533?hl=en) to troubleshoot and see how it goes...